# Paypal Split Payments / Adaptive Payments with Codeigniter. HOW?

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have an upcoming project where my client needs to be able to send a paypal payment to his own merchant paypal and the rest of the money to another paypal user. So say someone donates 50 bucks to joe blow, joe blow gets $45 in his paypal and the company gets $5 as a fee.

I know that I need codeigniter adaptive payments for this but I can't find a good adaptive payments library. Any ideas on how to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the PayPal SDKs at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#adaptivepaymentsnew.

This is not a codeigniter specific library but you will be able to use it nevertheless.